# How to refresh updated entity data without restarting the server

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I am using EclipseLink JPA as ORM and web logic 10.3 as an application server in my project. Everything working fine  until i got a bug for data refresh. Here is the case one of my entity table row is updated to new value but my entity manager or JPA did not pick that value. For this we have lite rely re started the server. then it picked up the value.

Here is my persistence.xml file and here is the way i am using entity manager in my class.

```
<persistence-unit name="BasePersistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/CTH_DS</jta-data-source> 
    <class>org.test.partyrequest.model.dataobject.RqstTrc</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>

    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="WebLogic_10" />
        <!-- Logging level is set to INFO, Need to change in Production -->
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE" />
        <property name="eclipselink.persistence-context.flush-mode" value="COMMIT" />
        <property name="eclipselink.persistence-context.close-on-commit" value="true" />
        <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false" />      
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

SPRING JPA XML FILE

```
<context:load-time-weaver aspectj-weaving="on" />

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="BasePersistenceUnit" />
</bean>

<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter" />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebLogicJtaTransactionManager" /> 

<!-- ========================= BUSINESS OBJECT DEFINITIONS ========================= -->

<!-- Instruct Spring to perform declarative transaction management automatically on annotated classes. -->
<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<!-- Post-processor to perform exception translation on @Repository classes
    (from native exceptions such as JPA PersistenceExceptions to Spring's DataAccessException hierarchy).
-->
<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
```

My Entity calss

```
@Entity
```

@Table(name = "PRTY_RQST")
public class PrtyRqst implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = -4679712398918736694L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "PRTY_RQST_PRTYRQSTID_GENERATOR")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "PRTY_RQST_PRTYRQSTID_GENERATOR", allocationSize = 1, sequenceName = "PRTY_RQST_SEQ")
@Column(name = "PRTY_RQST_ID")
private Long prtyRqstId;

@Column(name = "CHLD_RQST_IND")
private String chldRqstInd;

@Column(name = "PARNT_PRTY_RQST_ID")
private BigDecimal parntPrtyRqstId;

@Column(name = "PROCES_REFR")
private String procesRefr;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "RQST_DT_TM")
private Date rqstDtTm;

@Column(name = "UPDT_BY")
private String updtBy;

// bi-directional many-to-one association to PrtyKey
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "prtyRqst", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<PrtyKey> prtyKeys;

// bi-directional many-to-one association to PrtyRqstHist
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "prtyRqst", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@OrderBy("rqstDtTm DESC")
private List<PrtyRqstHist> prtyRqstHists;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "prtyRqst", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private RqstPayload rqstPayload;

// bi-directional many-to-one association to RqstTrc
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "prtyRqst", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<RqstTrc> rqstTrcs;

// bi-directional many-to-one association to AddtnRqstInfo
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "prtyRqst", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<AddtnRqstInfo> addtnRqstInfos;

// bi-directional many-to-one association to BusnApplc
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
@JoinColumn(name = "BUSN_APPLC_ID")
private BusnApplc busnApplc;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
@JoinColumn(name = "INTN_PROCES_TYP_ID")
private IntnProcesTyp intnProcesTyp;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
@JoinColumn(name = "INTN_STATS_ID")
private IntnStat intnStat;

@Column(name = "ORCHESTRATION_ID")
private String orchestrationId;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
@JoinColumn(name = "ALLW_CHNL_ID")
private AllwChnl allwChnl;

// bi-directional many-to-one association to RqstTyp
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
@JoinColumn(name = "RQST_TYP_ID")
private RqstTyp rqstTyp;

@Column(name = "TRACK_RQST_IND")
private String trackRqstInd;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "SUBMIT_DT_TM")
private Date submitDtTm;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "EFFECTIVE_DT")
private Date effectiveDt;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "RQST_CREATE_DT_TM")
private Date rqstCreateDtTm;
```

In my DAO IMPL class I have this.persist(prtyRqstDO);

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
    private PartyRequestBO createRequest(PartyRequestBO partyRequestBO, boolean isParent) throws RuntimeException {
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("Enter: PartyRequestsDAOImpl:createRequest()");
        }
        partyRequestBO.setOrchestrationID(generateOrchestrationId());
        PrtyRqst prtyRqstDO = PartyRequestEntityMapper.partyRequestMapper(partyRequestBO, isParent, true);
        try {
            this.persist(prtyRqstDO);
            partyRequestBO.setRequestIdentifier(prtyRqstDO.getPrtyRqstId());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if(log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                log.debug("PartyRequestsDAOImpl:createRequest : " + PartyRequestConstants.UNABLE_TO_INSERT, e);
            }
            throw new PartyRequestDataException(PartyRequestConstants.UNABLE_TO_INSERT, e);
        }
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("Exit: PartyRequestsDAOImpl:createRequest()");
        }
        return partyRequestBO;
    }


@Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void persist(T entity) {
    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
        log.debug("Enter: BaseDAO:persist() : " + entity);
    }
    this.getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
        log.debug("Exit: BaseDAO:persist()");
    }
}
public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
        log.debug("Enter: BaseDAO:getEntityManager() : " + this.entityManager);
    }
    return this.entityManager;
}
```

Here the problem is, if i update the row in one of the table through back end my application container is not picking the change.

Can any one Tell me? thank you in advance.

EDIT:

Thank you both of you. I have modified according to your comments added following lines of code.

```
this.entityManager.clear();
this.entityManager.close();
//this.getEntityManager().refresh(entityManager);
```

Here i could able to get the update value what i have done it through backend with out restarting server. But the problem is it hold all the changed values.

for example i have changed value to **FulOrderWSA** it was working. changed to **FulorderWSB** it was working again.Now i have tried for **FulOrderWSZ** it didn't work(DB values is FulorderWSB ).

Finally i tried here with old value that is **FulorderWSA** as per DB it should not work but it worked for me. what i noticed that it is holding all the DB changed values here.

How to get ride of this. I have used both clear and close for entityManager. can any one help me on this.

thank you.

Vijay.

Comment: How are you fetching entity from database, can you update post with relevant code.

Comment: updated the code snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks,

for all your support. Basically we are not using Cache from EclipseLink. we had bean that handles all the metadata initialization as init method. what we have done is, used JDK Timer to reload the particular Bean to refresh the data. It was working fine.

I have checked the time taking to refresh the all the methods are less than 500 milliseconds. I can foresee only issue when this thread is executing and there is a request.since it is taking less than 500 millisecs its ok for us.

I hope this will be helpful if someone is not using cache you can try this approach.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have turned off the EclipseLink shared cache (AKA second level cache), so the issue is likely that you are holding onto long lived EntityManagers.  Once an entity becomes managed by the EM, JPA requires that EM to return that exact instance from every find/query operation as it was when first read and any changes your app might have made to it.

There are a number of options.  The best is to look at your EntityManager lifecycle and only obtain an EntityManager when needed, and close it when done.  Or, just call em.clear() at points to prevent them from filling up, which will detach all entities associated to the em.  Make sure to flush changes though if you wish to keep the changes before calling clear.

If there is a specific entity you need to refresh, em.refresh(entity) will work.  This will clear any changes the application might have made though, and can be dangerous with cascade refresh settings mixed with lazy access - so use carefully or you may unintentionally wipe out changes to a whole tree at a later time.

Comment: Thank you Chris, i have added these 2 lines this.entityManager.clear();
this.getEntityManager().refresh(entityManager); to my api method but got the following error "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not refresh not managed object: Shared EntityManager proxy for target factory". can you help me.

Comment: Hi Chris, i have removed refresh and tested with clear(). I have changes one of the value to FulfillmentOrderWS to FulfillmentOrderWS123 it worked for me. so i have tested with FulfillmentOrderWS786 it worked for me. Great. but when i change back to FulfillmentOrderWS123 it was still working even for FulfillmentOrderWS though value is FulfillmentOrderWS786. I will tyr with close and let you know.

Comment: That means it is not managed.  How are you getting your entity?  You are using Spring, so I hope you are letting Spring manage your EMs, so you should just need to read in the entity again in a new context- try calling em.find() passing in the pk.  This should return a managed entity.  If it is stale still, call clear and then find or find and then refresh on the managed entity.

Comment: Thank for all your support.
Basically we are not using Cache from EclipseLink. we had bean that handles all the metadata initialization as init method.

Finally what we have done is used JDK Timer to reload the particular Bean again. It was working fine. I have checked the time taking to refresh the all the methods are less than 500 milliseconds.
I can foresee only issue when this thread is executing and there is a request.since it is less than 500 millisecs we chosen this push forward the issue. If any one thinks this not the best solution plz let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You have caching disabled, so you should see any database changes.

My guess is that you are hold onto a single EntityManager in your DAO.  This is very bad, as an EntityManger should be created per transaction, or per request, not held for the duration of the application.  It is also not thread safe, so holding onto a single one does not make sense, as it is a transactional object.

You seem to also be using Spring, so it might be proxying the EntityManager underneath and creating one per transaction, but perhaps you have not configured Spring or your transactions correctly.

Include the code the creating/configures the EntityManager.

Comment: Thank you James, i have added springjpa xml file. what i understood from you and Chris is that i need to have transaction then close after execution and flush it. is it right.